# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults stopped working using iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode6, nsuserdefaults, ios9.3

I'm using this code in my app:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"First_RUN"] == NULL) {
    [self tutorial:nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"First_RUN"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I'm using this code to know when the first time the app runs, if that is the case I show a tutorial.
After upgrading to 9.3.1 I found out that it stopped working so that every time the app runs tutorial appears.
Tried to debug this but it seems that [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] just stopped working.

I'm using old Xcode for this app (6.4). Any help using [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] in another way or explanation for this issue would help (I have this kind of code in many of my apps and it all breaks now).

Just to make things clear. This code runs perfectly with iOS 9.3 but not with iOS 9.3.1, I guess that something is broken or changed.

UPDATE: I created a test project for that (to isolate the issue), and it seems that simulator is fine but running on device with 9.3.1 even using Xcode 7.3 makes same issue: https://sidan5@bitbucket.org/sidan5/nsuserdefaultsdemo.git

Comment: Yep, Even put that just after the setInteger call. Doesn't work.
This app worked for years, so I believe something is wrong...

Comment: `synchronize` is *overestimated* and not needed. ;-)

Comment: This seems to be an iOS bug. I'm still having problems with NSUserDefaults occasionally not being loaded on 9.3.2. There's a thread about it on Apple Developer Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44264

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends to register default values to get a reliable default state.

In `AppDelegate` insert as soon as possible (in `awakeFromNib` or `applicationWill/DidFinishLaunching`)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *defaultValues = @{@"First_RUN" : @NO};
[defaults registerDefaults:defaultValues];
```

Now the key is always `NO` on the first run and you can write

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"First_RUN"] == NO) {
    [self tutorial:nil];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"First_RUN"];
}
```

Using a boolean or integer value you could always test for `NO / 0` with `boolForKey:` / `integerForKey:` rather than for `NULL` or `nil`:

> If a boolean / integer value is associated with defaultName in the user
>   defaults, that value is returned. Otherwise, NO / 0 is returned.

Comment: Have you tried it with 9.3.1? My code runs perfect on 9.3 and all previous iOS versions. 
Adding that in didFinishLaunching doesn't help.

Comment: @Idan I just tested the code in the simulator and on a real device on 9.3.1 (however with Xcode 7) and it worked fine.

Comment: my test project? It doesn't run fine here?
Which build are you using?

Comment: Your test project does not contain any custom code. I downloaded it and added the code I suggested. Works great (Xcode 7.3 - 7D175)

Comment: Suddenly that works (test project) but not on my app :(

Comment: Found how to solve that. Deleting the app and reinstall solves that. I think something is broken when you upgrade normally from store so NSUserDefaults doesn't work (saw something with WhatsApp having same issue).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently deleting the app and reinstall solves the issue. I guess something went wrong with NSUserDefaults when upgrading from 9.3 to 9.3.1

Comment: Didn't work in my case. Already deleted the app (as well as several others affected by what seems to be an iOS bug) and the issue persists. There's an ongoing thread about it here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44264